# Node.js app on Heroku does not wake from idle

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a simple node.js app on a single Heroku web dyno and unchanged for 1+ months. Recently, I've found the app does not return from idle as it should per Heroku docs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#the-dyno-manager).

Instead, my logs show no Heroku attempt to unidle on receiving an http request and the app returns a 503 error:

```
2014-06-08T08:07:22.736817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-06-08T08:07:22.736356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-06-08T08:07:27.844277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-06-08T08:07:26.009475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-06-08T16:37:36.565924+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=brisksoft.herokuapp.com request_id=5e7040c6-fe3b-44b1-bf99-fa0214df9e5c fwd="174.21.203.228" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-06-08T16:37:36.773503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=brisksoft.herokuapp.com request_id=92627039-51f6-4a99-bafa-2c6f3a96d5ea fwd="174.21.203.228" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I'm aware of automated workarounds to prevent sleeping via New Relic and Pingdom, but would prefer to actually solve this problem and have the Heroku dyno behave as documented.

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "agent-node",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "elementtree": "^0.1.6",
    "request": "^2.27.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "description": "Node.js application for Job Agent",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/brenbob/nodejs"
  },
  "author": "Brenden West",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/brenbob/nodejs/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/brenbob/nodejs"
}
```

Index.js is:

```
// index.js
var server = require("./server");

server.start();
```

And server.js:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url'); 
var api = require("./api");

function start() {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    switch(pathname) {
    case '/getjobs':
        api.getjobs(request, response);

    break;
    default:
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    }
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(process.env.PORT || 8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes problems just go away. I pushed a new build that added 'forever', and now my dyno obediently unidles.

Comment: Did you ever find a proper solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be anything to do with idling.  Your app is crashing when it's returned from idling.  Does it run locally?

Comment: yes, it runs locally. Also, it runs fine if I manually restart the server. Per Heroku docs, I should see a log entry when the dyno restarts, but these don't appear: 2011-05-30T22:17:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-05-30T22:17:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting